# Adding data from object to url in $stateprovider

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to add the id i get from

```
$state.go('state1', {obj: {id: request.id, title: request.title}}
```

to the URL in

```
angular.module('app')  
  .config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('state1', {
        url : '/edit',
        params: {obj: null},
        ...
      }); 
  });
```

I accessed the id in my Controller using

```
vm.id = $stateParams.obj.id;
```

and tried adding it to the url by trying

```
url : '/edit/:id'
url : '/edit/:obj.id'
```

I tried searching for a while but it's either they are passing params (not object) or they are passing an object but uses a static url. I'm new to Angular can someone point out what i'm missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter in the url needs to match what you're passing in. Try this:

```
$stateProvider
      .state('state1', {
        url : '/edit/:id',
        params: {obj: null},
        ...
      });
```

Then call using:

```
$state.go('state1', {id: request.id, obj: {id: request.id, title: request.title}}
```

Comment: I didn't know that was possible. Thank you very much for this! Works like a charm!!!

Comment: @ChesterLim You'll want to add a resolve function on the state to create the object if it doesn't exist.  Otherwise you have an "URL" that really isn't an URL anymore and you can get into some confusion if you're not at the very least guarding against nulls.